# How to extract a zipped folder that was split into multiple parts in MAC OS

Tags: macos, file, zip, gzip

I downloaded a big folder in Google Drive that was split into 5 parts:

```
Myfolder-20200911T192019Z-001.zip
Myfolder-20200911T192019Z-002.zip
Myfolder-20200911T192019Z-003.zip
Myfolder-20200911T192019Z-004.zip
Myfolder-20200911T192019Z-005.zip
```

I'm having some trouble to extract it into the single folder it originally is. Is there a straighforward way to unzip all of them together and recreate the original folder? Maybe some specific command in gzip? I didn't wish to install any program just to perform this task.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do `cat Myfolder-20200911T192019Z* > total.zip` to combine your zip files and then run `unzip total.zip`

Comment: This won't work... You can't simply `cat` two ZIP files.

Answer (score 5):

The above answer didn't work for me.
The files needed to be unzipped sequentially rather than just concatenated together.

For anyone coming here from a general search about combining zip files but specifically to combine multipart zips from Google Drive, I found this answer to be the one that worked:
https://superuser.com/questions/1255221/how-to-unzip-multiple-zip-files-into-a-single-directory-structure-e-g-google-d

i.e. for the above (creating an output directory to start with if necessary):

```
    mkdir outputFolder
    unzip "Myfolder-20200911T192019Z-00*" -d outputFolder
```